# How to detect number of children in a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

I'm trying to create an infinitely looping content slider. I currently have it looping 3 items but want to implement a function that will allow it to always loop without having to update the script.

What I'm wondering is, if I can create an if statement that says, "If x is greater than the number of elements in `.quote`, do this." Or would I have to assign `.quote` to a variable?

Here is the [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RArnone/spgmfg88/)

```
var x = 1;

$('.quote:nth-child(2)').hide();
$('.quote:nth-child(3)').hide();

$('#next').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if(x === 3){
        $('.quote:nth-child(' + x + ')').hide();
        x = 1;
        $('.quote:nth-child(' + x + ')').show();
    }
    else{
        $('.quote:nth-child(' + x + ')').hide();
        x++;
        $('.quote:nth-child(' + x + ')').show();
    }
});

$('#prev').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if(x === 1){
        $('.quote:nth-child(' + x + ')').hide();
        x = 3;
        $('.quote:nth-child(' + x + ')').show();
    }
    else{
        $('.quote:nth-child(' + x + ')').hide();
        x--;
        $('.quote:nth-child(' + x + ')').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Please learn about the `%` modulo operator, which is perfect for handling situations like this without masses of code repetition.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but I would do this instead, which works with any number of items: https://jsfiddle.net/spgmfg88/1/

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks for the tip, I'll definitely look into that.

Comment: @JasonP Do you think you would be able to break down what you did for me? I'd like to understand it better.

Comment: I am still all ears guys :) may the fool explain the down-vote on a working answer. 1 line of code. Simple as that. What is it. Does it not do what it is supposed to? Does not the next previous when clicked navigate you to the correct element. Doesn't the question write "I'm trying to create an infinitely looping content slider." Where is there wrong to explain the down-vote. Run the snippet and if it does not work then vote against it.

Comment: @PeterDarmis you have completely failed to understand the point of the question, which is to allow for _more than three items_ appearing as an _infinite (endless) loop of items_ without having to adjust the code.    The OP never said anything about wanting it to keep rotating _automatically_.

Comment: @Alnitak you are very wrong my friend i totally understood the question and i will provide you the small snippet needed for this to work for a lot of elements. More than 3. In the mean time the quickest way to do for those 3 elements on that snippet provided in that question above is also the best way. Thanks. ;)

Comment: @Alnitak just edited answer for n elements thanks. bye.

Comment: @PeterDarmis that is absolutely _not_ "the best way" - compare your 10 line callback function bodies with the 3 line function bodies in my own answer

Comment: @R.Arnone i provided a clean and easy to use as an answer. To my opinion this is more solid way. Your provided example is changed also to match any number of elements, since there where down-votes because "i completely did not get the question?". I think if you have advisers like Alnitak then you will miss a lot in coding.

Comment: @Alnitak that is the best way provided that i did not alter completely the code of the OP. If you still can't admit that then you might have a small problem. I just provided an answer that works and works fine for `n` elements. If you down-voted for using the word `best` in the answer's description then simply add a comment "i down-vote this because i don't consider it should use the word `best`", but then again that is what you already did maybe. Anyway i don't down-vote answers that work only if someone uses a word that might annoy me, but then again that is what i do...not you obviously

Comment: @R.Arnone please correct me if i am wrong but with the words `I'm trying to create an infinitely looping content slider.` you also mean a slider that automatically starts looping on it's own, for `n` elements and that you would have also the ability to start-stop on some other button click. To my opinion i did this. If you don't mean that then my bad. Best regards.

Comment: @PeterDarmis In all honesty, I wanted a infinitely looping slider in terms of, once it hits the last slide, it rolls back over to the first slide (which I had created). However, I wanted it to work with an infinite number of child elements; whereas mine only worked with 3.

Comment: @PeterDarmis no, I down voted you at the point when you'd misread the question completely.   You subsequently commented that your change is the "quickest", which I don't dispute, but _also_ that it's the "best", which is very much disputed.  Thanks for the revenge downvote BTW!

Comment: @Alnitak i will still explain the *best* since you want it. Infinite looping means that something starts on it's own. You don't need to press a button. But you need your buttons to work properly. Given the code the OP presented the answer with the least changes that does exactly what he wants is mine. You have a very good answer sir but you just show off better skills in code-writing something that comes with experience. I did something else in case you saw. I took the lines of code of the OP and with 3 small changes made it work as he wants.

Comment: @Alnitak your answer regarding coding facts is less lines, of course you have not provided the "infinite looping" part, but as code-writing it is better than the example given by the OP. And to explain again, my answer sir is just based on the code of the OP i did not re-write it from scratch.

Comment: @R.Arnone my bad then since by the words "infinite looping" i understood something that loops forever... So that is the 1st thing i did not understand. The second is that i simply did three edits to your code to make it work for `n` elements and not `3`. My choice was not to write something from scratch when what you wanted could be done with a small correction on your code, and of course other people had already presented answers like that, like @Alnitak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "If x is greater than the number of elements in .quote, do this." Or would I have to assign .quote to a variable?

Without a variable

```
if (x > $('.quote').length) { do stuff... }
```

but you can assign it to a variable, too. That's more efficient, since you aren't performing the length calculation over and over unnecessarily - as long as the length doesn't change.

```
var quote = $('.quote').length;
if (x > quote) { do stuff... }
```

Comment: Please note that it is _completely possible_ to do this without any `if` conditions in the code at all (thereby eliminating a lot of code repetition)

Comment: @Alnitak I know your code eliminates 'if' conditions and it works but I don't understand the code as well as I do using 'if' statements. I like to use code I understand so if I ever come across an issue I have some idea of where to start troubleshooting.

Comment: @R.Arnone hence the hint in the first comment above (on the question) about the modulo operator (and I've just expanded on my answer).   Working from a base of 0, rather than 1 (because it makes the math easier), if you're already on the last element then `(n + 1) % length === 0`, i.e. it loops back, just the same as how the minute hand on a clock goes back to 0 after it goes to 59.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, which uses modulo arithmetic to automatically wrap from the last item to the first (or vice versa) without using any `if` conditions or repeating logic.

```
// current position, and cache of child nodes

var x = 0;
var $q = $('.container').children('.quote');

// increase or decrease X, wrapping within the number of elements

$('#next').on('click', function() {
    $q.eq(x).hide();
    x = (x + 1) % $q.length;              // increase x, with wrapping
    $q.eq(x).show();
});

$('#prev').on('click', function() {
    $q.eq(x).hide();
    x = (x + $q.length - 1) % $q.length;  // decrease x, with wrapping
    $q.eq(x).show();
});
```

The extra addition in `x = x + $q.length - 1` is there to ensure that x never becomes negative.

See https://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/5xfyk1e4/1/

Comment: I have just checked your Fiddle i don't see the continuous loop that should start when a user lands on the page that has the slider. Isn't that the question. `n` elements and... "I'm trying to create an infinitely looping content slider." When using the word "infinitely looping" means that this loops by it's own also. What exactly did i get wrong? I down-vote your answer because it works partially. I did not see the "infinitely looping" part.

Comment: @PeterDarmis As the OP already explained, he wanted one that's not bounded by the _length of the list of elements_, not "infinite in time".  By that token you should've down voted every other answer, too.

Comment: With you sir i will re-learn what "infinite loop" means i think... if "infinite looping" does not mean "infinite in time" then it is not "infinite" :) ;)

Comment: And please don't continue the argument it is already showing that it is a sad joke. Only no-one is laughing when you write that "infinite looping" does not really mean in time.... yep that was a nice one... ok i am sorry i won't write in any more the word "best". Sorry sir yours is the best. Less lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

This should achieve the infinite scrolling for you. (What I did in next/prev buttons was, fist hide the current object, then just show the x+1/x-1 object accordingly. But in between this I made a check to reset the x if reached the limits of object-count or 0, in the next or prev buttons respectively.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('jQuery started.');

  var x = 1;

  $('.quote:nth-child(2)').hide();
  $('.quote:nth-child(3)').hide();

  $('#next').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.quote:nth-child(' + x + ')').hide();
    if (x > $('.quote').length) {
         x=1;
    }
    else {
        x++;
    }
    $('.quote:nth-child(' + x  + ')').show();
  });

  $('#prev').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.quote:nth-child(' + x + ')').hide();
    if (x == 0) {
         x=1;
    }
    else {
        x--;
    }
    $('.quote:nth-child(' + x  + ')').show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/rvm1Lx4x/

OR

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('jQuery started.');

  $('.quote').hide();
  
    $('.quote:first').show().addClass("first");
    $('.quote').last().addClass("last");

  $('#next').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  var active = $('.quote:visible');
    
    if($(active).hasClass("last")){
     $('.quote.first').show();
      $(active).hide();
    }
    else{
      $(active).hide().next().show();
    }
    
  });

  $('#prev').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  var active = $('.quote:visible');
    
    if($(active).hasClass("first")){
     $('.quote.last').show();
      $(active).hide();
    }
    else{
      $(active).hide().prev().show();
    }
    
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider {
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 28px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
}

p {}

h3 {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#prev {}

#prev:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#next {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

#next:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div class="slider">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="quote">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum, erat sed aliquet vestibulum, est sapien pharetra mi, nec scelerisque eros justo et mauris. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus sagittis augue varius enim cursus tempus. Praesent
          lacinia a dui non hendrerit. Suspendisse sit amet euismod enim. Sed suscipit ultrices imperdiet.</p>
        <h3>John Doe</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="quote">
        <p>Morbi consectetur augue sit amet tristique dapibus. Mauris convallis arcu nec velit commodo congue. Pellentesque ac lectus a quam tristique lacinia. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
        <h3>John Doe</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="quote">
        <p>In velit lorem, lobortis ut sem non, pharetra porta leo. Donec odio leo, finibus quis suscipit eu, vulputate vitae elit. Ut sodales ultrices malesuada. Sed luctus porta lorem a sodales. Vivamus bibendum elit et augue sagittis, ac convallis massa
          suscipit.
        </p>
        <h3>John Doe</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
      <a id="prev" href="#">Previous</a>
      <a id="next" href="#">Next</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

$('.quote').children().length;

Comment: Please explain how your code solves the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your case and the way your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RArnone/spgmfg88/) is now the quickest and most efficient way to have a continuous slider without messing up a lot of what you already have written, is to place this small snippet in your code.

```
setInterval(function() {$('#next').trigger("click")},3000);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('jQuery started.');
  var x = 1;
  // check how many elements you have
  var n = $('.quote').length;
 
  $('.quote').not(':nth-child(0)').hide();

  $('#next').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // check if you reached last element
    if (x === n) {
      $('.quote:nth-child(' + x + ')').hide();
      x = 1;
      $('.quote:nth-child(' + x + ')').show();
    } else {
      $('.quote:nth-child(' + x + ')').hide();
      x++;
      $('.quote:nth-child(' + x + ')').show();
    }
  });

  $('#prev').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x === 1) {
      $('.quote:nth-child(' + x + ')').hide();
      // set to last
      x = n;
      $('.quote:nth-child(' + x + ')').show();
    } else {
      $('.quote:nth-child(' + x + ')').hide();
      x--;
      $('.quote:nth-child(' + x + ')').show();
    }
  });
  /* always loop by simply "clicking" next in case you don't need
  to start automatically */
  setInterval(function() {$('#next').trigger("click")},3000);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider {
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 28px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
}

p {}

h3 {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#prev {}

#prev:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#next {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

#next:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div class="slider">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="quote">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum, erat sed aliquet vestibulum, est sapien pharetra mi, nec scelerisque eros justo et mauris. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus sagittis augue varius enim cursus tempus. Praesent
          lacinia a dui non hendrerit. Suspendisse sit amet euismod enim. Sed suscipit ultrices imperdiet.</p>
        <h3>John Doe</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="quote">
        <p>Morbi consectetur augue sit amet tristique dapibus. Mauris convallis arcu nec velit commodo congue. Pellentesque ac lectus a quam tristique lacinia. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
        <h3>John Doe</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="quote">
        <p>In velit lorem, lobortis ut sem non, pharetra porta leo. Donec odio leo, finibus quis suscipit eu, vulputate vitae elit. Ut sodales ultrices malesuada. Sed luctus porta lorem a sodales. Vivamus bibendum elit et augue sagittis, ac convallis massa
          suscipit.
        </p>
        <h3>John Doe</h3>
      </div>
      
      <div class="quote">
        <p>No1 In velit lorem, lobortis ut sem non, pharetra porta leo. Donec odio leo, finibus quis suscipit eu, vulputate vitae elit. Ut sodales ultrices malesuada. Sed luctus porta lorem a sodales. Vivamus bibendum elit et augue sagittis, ac convallis massa
          suscipit.
        </p>
        <h3>John Doe</h3>
      </div>
      
      <div class="quote">
        <p>No2 In velit lorem, lobortis ut sem non, pharetra porta leo. Donec odio leo, finibus quis suscipit eu, vulputate vitae elit. Ut sodales ultrices malesuada. Sed luctus porta lorem a sodales. Vivamus bibendum elit et augue sagittis, ac convallis massa
          suscipit.
        </p>
        <h3>John Doe</h3>
      </div>
      
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
      <a id="prev" href="#">Previous</a>
      <a id="next" href="#">Next</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```